# How to setup multiple dropdowns in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

Someone know ho to setup multiple dropdowns in vuetify
I am new to learning in this framework.
Let me explain
In this situation im need to display all categories, subcategories and parent categories
In finish result im want get something like this
Anyway thanks for help

```
<ul>
  <li>Category
    <ul>
      <li>SubCategory 1.1
        <ul>
          <li>
             Parent Category
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>SubCategory 1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  (...)
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You will need to bind each dropdown to a data member.
2. Add a watch to the data member, and when it changes, repopulate the other dropdowns and the default value.

Setting `immediate` in the watcher will call the handler when loaded, before the user selects an item, and populates the initial state.

```
https://codepen.io/Flamenco/pen/xovKLq
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    item: "color",
    item2: "red",
    items: ["color", "number"],
    items2: "null"
  }),
  watch: {
    item: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(value) {
        if (value === "color") {
          this.items2 = ["red", "blue"];
          this.item2 = "red";
        } else {
          this.items2 = ["1", "2", "3"];
          this.item2 = "1";
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <div style='width:3in'>
      <v-select v-model='item' :items='items' label='Select 1'></v-select>
      <v-select v-model='item2' :items='items2' label='Select 2'></v-select>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much nice solution